# What is the difference between "common" and "mutual"?

Tags: adjectives

What is the difference between "He is our common teacher" and "He is our mutual teacher"?

Comment: I don't think I would use (or hear) either. And I find it hard to tell the difference between two equally unlikely things.

Comment: Depends if you have a subject with a name that is abbreviated to *common* or *mutual*. Just say *He is our teacher*.

Answer (score 4):

As RegDwight alludes to, a more idiomatic way of saying this would be *He teaches both of us* or (very colloquially) *He is both of our's teacher*. (Standard English does not have a good way of forming possessives from phrases like *both of us*. The construction *both of our's* is how I would form this in speech, but I would never use that in writing, and it looks pretty strange when written down.)

As for the difference between *common* and *mutual*, the word *common* is used whenever two people share something, while *mutual* usually implies reciprocity. That is:

- *We have a common interest*: We both are interested in the same thing, it is an interest which we share.
- *We have a mutual interest*: We are interested in each other.

Comment: The only tweak I'd make to the above answer is what @oerkelens states below. "Common" indicates two or more share or have access to something. Typically there's little or no exclusivity to something that's common.

Answer (score 2):

"Common" indicates that two (or more) parties share something, like a hobby, an interest, or a room. 
If among all your teachers, only that one teacher teaches both of you, you could indicate that that teacher is your common teacher, to distinguish him or her from all the others. It would not be a very common use of this construction, though, and it might not be immediately clear what you mean.

"Mutual" describes the similar, equal or reciprocal involvement in an action performed by or between several actors. If you and someone else are mutual teachers, I would understand that to mean that you both learn from one another. In the given example, I can make head nor tail of it.

Mutual is used in expressions like "mutual respect", meaning that both parties respect the other party, and this is not the kind of respect between, say, a pop-artist and a fan. "Mutual understanding" indicates that both sides are willing to make an effort to see each other's points, and come to an understanding that is not mono-directional.

I realize that this is far from a complete answer, but I hope some of the examples can clear some things up a bit :)

Comment: I understand that this phrase is very unnatural, but I asked because in the "books" section of Google, there are many examples of reputable authors using those terms, so I was curious as to the difference, if any.

Comment: Here are some examples that I found: I found myself learning more about Plato from him than from anyone around, incluing our common teacher, Festugiere.

Comment: But she did request me not to tell our mutual teacher about what she did for a living.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the Original Poster has been discussing some problems arising from the use of the term *our mutual friend*. This famous phrase was used as the title of a Dickens novel. The phrase is commonly used to mean that two people, let us say A and B, have a friend in common. That is to say the word *mutual* in relationship to the word *friend* is often used to  mean that two people share a third friend. In other words, as far as common usage goes, *mutual* is indeed used to mean *common*.

However,  it is often pointed out that in fact this is not the original meaning of the term. What is being underlined, it is said, in the original term *mutual friend*, is not that A and B share a friend, but that A and B have a friend, and this friend reciprocates this feeling of friendship. In other words the friendly regard between the couple of people and the third party is mutual - the third party regards the pair in the same light. Fusspots everywhere who delight in tripping people up, relish the opportunity of pointing this out, when people use *mutual friend* to mean shared friend.

However, in most other situations a *mutual* relationship does indeed describe  a reciprocal relationship. If two people are mutual admirers, they both admire *each other*. Two people who have a common admirer, have an admirer who admires them both. They, however, may not like the admirer at all!

Comment: IIRC, in the Dickens novel the phrase is spoken by an uneducated man, meaning "the friend we have in common". The author's choice to use it as his title has led to its becoming well-known and people thinking it is correct.